# Manter id e id_usuario igual no updateOrCreate

Tags: php, laravel-eloquent, slim

Oi, usando o *Slim Framework* para *php*, eu estou tentando fazer um `updateOrCreate`:

```
$eventos = Eventos::updateOrCreate(
     ["id" => $id, "id_usuario" => $id_usuario], 
     ["nome" => $nome, "descricao" => $descricao]
);
```

O problema é que quando for fazer o *update* ele tem q manter o `id_usuario` e o `id`, pensei em colocar o `id_usuario` no primeiro "[]" mas ele dá o seguinte erro:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '91' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `eventos` (`id`,
>   `id_usuario`, `nome`) values (91, 1, Kashmir))

Ele dá insert em vez de update pois, como posso resolver isso ?

---

Segue o model da tabela Eventos:

```
<?php

    class Eventos extends BaseModel{

        protected $table = "eventos";

        const UPDATED_AT = 'atualizado_em';
        const CREATED_AT = 'criado_em';

        protected $dateFormat = 'U';
        protected $fillable = ["id", "nome", "descricao", "id_thumbnail", "local", "endereco", "place_id", "data_hora_inicio", "data_hora_fim", "responsavel", "telefone1", "telefone2", "email", "site", "nota", "status", "categoria", "facebook_page_url", "id_usuario", "preco"];

    }

?>
```

Comment: Você está usando Eloquent? Tem o layout dessa tabela

Comment: Se ele está criando é porque não existe um evento com o mesmo `id` e `id_usuario` que você está passando. Esse `id_usuario` já foi cadastrado com `id` diferente. Adicione (Antes do seu código)  `\DB::listen(function($sql) {
            var_dump($sql);
        });` e verifique a `query` gerada. Assim você verá o erro.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic estou usando o Eloquent sim, vou atualizar a pergunta com o model da tabela

Comment: Alan o `id` é `auto_incremento`? se for ela não pode estar no `$fillable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código executado [updateOrCreate](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L592) é:

```
public static function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = array())
{
    $instance = static::firstOrNew($attributes);
    $instance->fill($values)->save();
    return $instance;
}
```

---

```
public static function firstOrNew(array $attributes)
{
    if ( ! is_null($instance = static::where($attributes)->first()))
    {
        return $instance;
    }
    return new static($attributes);
}
```

então o correto seria:

```
$eventos = Eventos::updateOrCreate(
    ["id" => $id], 
    ["nome" => $nome, "descricao" => $descricao, "id_usuario" => $id_usuario]
);
```

onde a busca é pela sua identificação, inclusive no seu model tem a configuração errada, onde o `id` não tem que ficar dentro `$fillable`, porque o mesmo é gerado automáticamente pela banco, então:

```
class Eventos extends BaseModel
{

    protected $table = "eventos";

    const UPDATED_AT = 'atualizado_em';
    const CREATED_AT = 'criado_em';

    protected $dateFormat = 'U';
    protected $fillable = ["nome","descricao", "id_thumbnail", 
                           "local", "endereco", "place_id", 
                           "data_hora_inicio", "data_hora_fim", 
                           "responsavel", "telefone1", 
                           "telefone2", "email", "site", "nota", 
                           "status", "categoria", 
                           "facebook_page_url", "id_usuario","preco"];

}
```

---

Eu particularmente faria assim:

```
$evento = Eventos::find($id);
if (!$evento) 
{
    $evento = new Eventos();
    $evento->fill(["nome"=>$nome,"descricao"=>$descricao,"id_usuario"=>$id_usuario]);
}
else
{
    $evento->fill(["nome"=>$nome,"descricao"=>$descricao]);
}
$evento->save();
```

Também pode ser criado um [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes) no seu `model`:

```
class Eventos extends BaseModel
{

    protected $table = "eventos";

    const UPDATED_AT = 'atualizado_em';
    const CREATED_AT = 'criado_em';

    protected $dateFormat = 'U';
    protected $fillable = ["nome","descricao", "id_thumbnail", 
                           "local", "endereco", "place_id", 
                           "data_hora_inicio", "data_hora_fim", 
                           "responsavel", "telefone1", 
                           "telefone2", "email", "site", "nota", 
                           "status", "categoria", 
                           "facebook_page_url", "id_usuario","preco"];

    public function scopeGeneration($query, $id, $values = array())
    {
        $m = $query->find($id);
        if (!m)
        {
           $m = new Eventos();                              
        }  
        else
        {
          unset($values['id_usuario']);
        }          
        $m ->fill($values);
        $m->save();
        return $m;
    }

}
```

Como usar:

```
$values = ["nome"=>$nome,"descricao"=>$descricao,"id_usuario"=>$id_usuario];
$evento = Eventos::generation($id,$values);
```

Comment: eu preciso que o id_usuario seja criado no insert mas no update não, no update eu quero manter o id_usuario que já tá no banco, por isso pensei em fazer do jeito que tá na pergunta...sabe como resolver esse problema ?

Comment: vou arrumar o problema do id no $fillable, vlw!

Comment: Olha só @AlanPS vou editar e colocar o `id_usuario` no segundo array! faça o teste

Comment: o problema de colocar o id_usuario é q quando der update vai atualizar o campo no banco, eu podia fazer outra query verificando se existe no banco o registro e caso exista colocar um if pra tirar o id_usuario mas acho q seria "feio" fazer assim, pensei que o eloquent tivesse uma forma melhor de fazer isso

Comment: @AlanPS ele vai atualizar o id_usuario para o mesmo número ou não ?

Comment: não, é justamente isso, ele vai mudar o id_usuario e eu não quero isso, não pode atualizar o id_usuario, só criar

Comment: AlanPS vou fazer outra solução pera ae

Comment: pronto @AlanPS.

Comment: @AlanPS fiz outro exemplo com scope.