# Retorno de Collection após Update

Tags: laravel

Por padrão o Laravel devolve true ou false ao fazer um update.

Exemplo:

```
User::find(1)->update(['name'=> 'David']);
```

O retorno disso será um true ou false, fazendo com que eu precise fazer outro Find para pegar a collection do User.

Existe alguma maneira de o retorno deste update ser a própria collection atualizada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe nada pronto pelo `Framework` `Laravel` mas, existe como fazer um método para resolver o problema de atualização e depois o retorno da coleção com [Query Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes):

Dentro da sua classe `User` crie um método:

```
public function scopeUpdateGetCollection($query, $id, $data)
{
    $model = $query->find($id);
    if ($model)
    {
        if ($model->update($data))
        {
            return $model->get();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

e utilize da seguinte forma:

```
$collection = User::updateGetCollection(1, ['name'=> 'David']);
```

nesse caso em especifico foi feito um método que é responsável em `salvar` as atualizações e depois `mostrar a coleção` existente na sua tabela.

***Outros exemplos***:

- [Para que serve um scope no Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148776/para-que-serve-um-scope-no-laravel/151866#151866)
- [Como configurar um Anonymous Global Scopes no Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274713/como-configurar-um-anonymous-global-scopes-no-laravel/274721#274721)
- [Manter id e id_usuario igual no updateOrCreate](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273788/manter-id-e-id-usuario-igual-no-updateorcreate/273905#273905)

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Laravel - Eloquent Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes)</sub>

Comment: Excelente Virgilio! Isso resolve mesmo o problema!
Outra alternativa que acabei de pensar é não utilizar o Model diretamente para isso e sim o repositório, e lá implementar da forma que você sugeriu também.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Está errada a afirmação da pergunta. `find` não retorna `Collection`, retorna o `Model`.

E é fácil resolver o problema se você estiver usando uma variável e salvando o resultado da consulta nela.

Veja:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->update(...);

dd($user); // Valor atualizado
```

Com a invenção da função `tap` nas versões mais novas do Laravel, você poderia fazer assim:

```
return tap(User::find(1))->update([
    'name' => $name,
    'age' => $age,
]);
```

Agora, se seu questionamento for em relação ao `update` que é retornado do Query Builder, você realmente precisará fazer outra consulta, já que o update não é feito em cima de cada item da collection, e sim diretamente no banco.

Exemplo:

```
 $query = User::where(['x' => 'y']);

 $query->update(['z' => 'x']);

 $users = $query->get();
```

Comment: Excelente Wallace, muito obrigado! Aprendi bastante com sua resposta!