# Usar campo retornado do find para adicionar mais resultados na mesma query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.2

No código abaixo eu busco um produto e pego o campo "relacionado" dele para fazer uma busca no banco trazendo todos os produtos (incluindo ele mesmo) que possuem o mesmo valor nesse campo.

É possível fazer tudo isso com apenas uma *query* invés de duas?

```
$produto = Produto::find(7996);

$relacionados = Produto::where('relacionado', $produto->relacionado)->get();
```

Comment: Dá para fazer uma subQuery para a busca do `produto->relacionado`? seria isso?

Comment: Isso. Como eu poderia passar o valor do campo "relacionado" do produto encontrado no find para essa subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se pode utilizar o `whereRaw` para escrever uma `Sub Query` da seguinte forma:

```
$subQuery = 'relacionado = (SELECT relacionado FROM produto WHERE id=? limit 1)';
Produto::whereRaw($subQuery, array(7996))->get();
```

seria então uma `SQL` mas, tendo uma `SubQuery` para a busca do campo `relacionado`.

A forma que você fez não é errada só é errado trazer todos os campos que não são exigidos para a segunda pesquisa, uma otimização:

```
$result = Produto::where('id', 7996)->select('relacionado')->first(); // otimizado
$relacionados = Produto::where('relacionado', $result->relacionado)->get();
```

Uma resumo do código [pode ser feito como explicado nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280124/retorno-de-collection-ap%C3%B3s-update/280136#280136), com [Query Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes) da seguinte forma:

Crie um método na sua classe `Produto`:

```
public function scopeRelacionado($query, $id)
{
    $subQuery = 'relacionado = (SELECT relacionado FROM produto WHERE id=? limit 1)';
    return $query::whereRaw($subQuery, array($id))->get();
}
```

e utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
Produto::relacionado(7996);
```